# How to fit a fixed document for printing?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.8

I am currently developing a WPF application using C# language and .Net Framework 4.8
In the `MainWindow` I have the `Print` menu button to generate a `Fixed Document` like this

```
    private void clPrintMenu_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

       /* Margins is a User-defined structure to set Top, Right, Bottom and Left values
          in Cm, Inches and Pixels */
        Margins margins = new Margins(21, 29.7);
        margins.Unit = Units.Pixel;
        Size sz = new Size(margins.Left.Value, margins.Top.Value);

        FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();
        document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = sz;

        /* CashJournal is a UserControl designed as an A4 sheet the list below contains several
           Cashjournal which represent multiple pages */
        List<CashJournal> journals = CashJournal.PrintJournals;
        foreach (CashJournal jrl in journals)
        {
            FixedPage page = new FixedPage();
            page.Width = margins.Left.Value;
            page.Height = margins.Top.Value;

            FixedPage.SetLeft(jrl, 0);
            FixedPage.SetTop(jrl, -20);
            page.Children.Add(jrl);

            PageContent content = new PageContent();
            ((IAddChild)content).AddChild(page);

            document.Pages.Add(content);
        }

        /* The document is then passed to a window for preview */
        CashPrintPreview dialog = new CashPrintPreview(selectedTab, document);
        dialog.ShowDialog();
    }
```

In the CashPrintPreview, the document is displayed in a `DocumentViewer` which has a `Print` button. I modifed the `Print() CommandBinding` to bind the function to my custom function `PrintPreview`

```
    private void PrintView(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
        bool? rslt = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (rslt != true)
            return;

        /* This block is my problem */
        PrintQueue queue = dialog.PrintQueue;
        PrintCapabilities capabilities = queue.GetPrintCapabilities();
        Size sz = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);
        document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = sz;
        XpsDocumentWriter writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(queue);
        writer.Write(document);
    }
```

When I choose the `XPS printer` from the `PrintDialog`, the created file render perfectly as it appears in the preview. But when I choose the `PDF printer` from Adobe the document is not well scaled like too much margins on top and not enough margins on left.

How can I resolve this issue. Thanks.
PS. Please be explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am finally able to print a `FixedDocument` to PDF using the Acrobat printer. I just needed to pass my `document` to the `PrintDocument` function of the chosen printer:

```
private void PrintView(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
  
  bool? rslt = dialog.ShowDialog();
  if (rslt != true)
    return;

  dialog.PrintDocument(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)document).DocumentPaginator, "");
}
```